# Convex Hull calculation in Point Cloud Library fails in 2 as well as 3 dimensions

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, convex-hull, qhull

i'm following the tutorial of the PCL docs for calculating a 2D Convex Hull [see here](http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/convex_hull2d.php).

I have a cloud and some indices, project them on a plane with given coefficients and then calculate the convex hull. Here's the code:

```
PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr tmpInliers(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>());

ProjectInliers<PointXYZ> proj;
proj.setModelType(SACMODEL_PLANE);
proj.setInputCloud(someCloud); 
proj.setIndices(someIndices); 
proj.setModelCoefficients(someCoefficients);
proj.filter(*tmpInliers);

PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr hull(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>());
ConvexHull<PointXYZ> chull;
chull.setInputCloud(tmpInliers);
chull.setComputeAreaVolume(true);
chull.setDimension(3); <--- see below
chull.reconstruct(*hull);
```

The results i get for the total area and volume are around:

```
  Area & Volume of convex hull: 7.8726e-312 2.122e-314
```

For values of **tmpInliers** ranging around

```
(-0.80562,-0.787018,2.25184)
(-0.477351,-0.798953,2.11432)
(-0.633823,-0.750283,2.96717)
[....]
```

If i change "setDimensions" to "2" i get the following error

```
[pcl::ConvexHull::performReconstrution2D] ERROR: qhull was unable to compute a convex hull for the given point cloud (size of cloud)!
```

In the following example i am constructing a example and fail in every case (setDimension set to 2 or 3) with one of the failures from before (either "qhull was unable..." or a strange result according to values from the ConvexHull.

```
PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr hugeBox(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>());
hugeBox->push_back(PointXYZ(10, 10, 10));
hugeBox->push_back(PointXYZ(10, 10, -10));
hugeBox->push_back(PointXYZ(10, -10, 10));
hugeBox->push_back(PointXYZ(10, -10, -10));
hugeBox->push_back(PointXYZ(-10, 10, 10));
hugeBox->push_back(PointXYZ(-10, 10, -10));
hugeBox->push_back(PointXYZ(-10, -10, 10));
hugeBox->push_back(PointXYZ(-10, -10, -10));

// Project inliers onto plane model
PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr hugePlane(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>());
ProjectInliers<PointXYZ> proj;
proj.setModelType(SACMODEL_PLANE);
proj.setInputCloud(hugeBox);
proj.setModelCoefficients(coefficients);
proj.filter(*hugePlane);

// get the convex hull of plane
vector<Vertices> polygonsOut;
PointCloud<PointXYZ>::Ptr hugeHull(new PointCloud<PointXYZ>());
ConvexHull<PointXYZ> chull;
chull.setInputCloud(hugePlane);
chull.setDimension(2);
chull.reconstruct(*hugeHull, polygonsOut);
```

I'm a little stuck here. Why does it fail if i set it to 2 dimensions? And if i set it to 3 dimensions i occasionaly the following warning:

```
qhull precision warning: 
The initial hull is narrow (cosine of min. angle is 0.9999999999999991).
A coplanar point may lead to a wide facet.
```

I understand that this is the case if i have a planar projection, but how to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem was that PCL was linking to an old *libqhull* (*v0.5*) from the system instead to the newer *v0.6*  which was present but not correctly linked. 
Problems do not occur regularly but in some special cases with the old version, like if you have a planar projection from 3d to 2d and try to put a hull around it.

I will submit a request to the pcl-people to add a requirement for the version number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the framework you are using, but let me have a guess: You are projecting the points on a plane embedded in a 3-dimensional volume, am I right? It's quite straightforward that the 3-dimensional convex hull algorithm fails, because the points projected on the plane are coplanar - by definition. Other way round, even if they are projected on the plane, which is embedded in a 3-dimensional space, the points reside in an 3-dimensional space, too - I guess. The 2-d convex hull algorithm on the other hand expects real 2-dimensional points - most likely. Thus, I think it'll do reducing the projected points to a real 2-dimensional space by means of some sort of mapping and then apply the 2-d convex hull algorith.

Comment: The 2d algorithm fails as well, see the 4th codeblock in my post.
And if i change the PointXYZ to PointXY in the hull calculation i get a linker error. Seems not to be built for that.
Furthermore, i took parts of the code from the official PCL-Docs area.

Comment: This is **excactly** what I was trying to point out. You'll have to know how to convert your PointXYZ to PointXY by some conversion - not just replace the types - and then try and run it.

Comment: I tried this via copyPointCloud(*in, *out), didn't work. But i found the problem, see post below. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but after putting the data on PCL_VIEWER, it showed the point cloud as a set of parallel lines, so when I manipulated the planar projection, the original data became planar lines, and ConvelHull Algorithm could not accept such an input, and I still did not solve it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).